# testing authorize.net Automatic recorring billing

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

i have implemented the Authorize.net Automatic recorring billing using XM (in test mode). I need to test my work. But i don't know how to test it.

Does any one know this?

Comment: hi @Histack can you share how to implement the recurring billing with ios

Answer (score 0):

To test it simply sign up for a [developer account](https://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/) and then use their development server to process ARB subscriptions. It works just like the live server does so you can fully test out all of the functionality before going live and being confident that it will all work.

Comment: Not exactly, maybe you should tell us how to process a recurring payment from within the dashboard as your answer suggests ? Seems to be no way to fire a ARB subscription of one time from the dashboard.... only way to test in reality is to set a 1 day ARB ?? or are we to assume its the same event type as net.authorize.payment.authcapture.created that contains no useful data at all.